# PyQT5 - how can i get the QApplication to call a method once it is loaded?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I would like to write in a QTextEdit as soon as the main window is loaded, how can I do that efficiently ?

I tried changing a boolean value once `app.exec()` is called but since that's the main application loop, it does not work.

The only current solutions I have ( and that I would like to avoid ) are doing a timer or asking the user to press a button that I link to the method.

I tried looking into the signals sent by QApplication, QGuiApplication and the parents but could not find a signal related to the main window having loaded anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something has to happen as soon as a widget is [going to be] shown, you can do it in the `showEvent()` method:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    firstShown = False

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super().showEvent(event)
        if not self.firstShown:
            self.firstShown = True
            self.textEdit.setPlainText('hello')
```

Note that this does not exactly happen as soon as the window is shown (there's a moltitude of reason for this, including the fact that the system's "window manager" might need some time to actually show the widget); In such cases, it *is* safe enough to use a singleshot QTimer set to 0:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    firstShown = False

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super().showEvent(event)
        if not self.firstShown:
            self.firstShown = True
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.doStartupEvents)

    def doStartupEvents(self):
        self.textEdit.setPlainText('hello')
```

Another theoretical possibility is to do those events in the paintEvent (ensuring that they happen *only* the first time), but I wouldn't suggest it.